# Quartz.Net реакция главного приложения на окончание работы по расписанию (IJob)

Tags: c#, многопоточность, quartz

Есть Quartz.Net sheduller и его  Listeners, а именно TriggerListeners, JobListeners, SchedulerListeners. 
Какие из слушателей работают из запускающего потока а какие в своих собственных?
Есть ли возможность из слушателя или непосредственно работы (Job) заставить основной поток выполнить действие в своем (главном, основном) контексте?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю зачем это нужно, но если нужно передать окружение метода, в котором инициализируется `IScheduler`, то можно создать кастомизированную реализацию `IJobFactory` и в ее конструктор передать необходимые вещи, главное что бы Dispose на них не вызвался раньше, чем они бы были использованы в `IJob`

Пример:

```
static class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        var _kernel = new StandardKernel(new DIConfig());
        var _scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.JobFactory = new MyCustomJobFactory(_kernel);
        // тут добавить триггеры и типы, реализующие IJob
        Console.ReadKey();
        _scheduler.Shutdown();
     }
}

class MyCustomJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public JobFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(kernel));
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var qwe = Activator.CreateInstance(bundle.JobDetail.JobType, _kernel);
        return qwe as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
}
```

**Примечание**: по факту в моем коде kernel - это DI контейнер, и он инстанцировал реализации IJob с инъекцией зависимостей через ctor, в данном случае kernel используется только для демонстрации и на его месте могло быть что угодно...

Comment: какой то странный метод public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }, что он делает? в смысле в чем его смысл